# Graphing a histogram overlaid with a fitted 2 parameter Weibull function

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting

I would like to plot both a histogram to a fitted Weibull function on the same graph. The code to plot the histogram is:

```
    hist(data$grddia2, prob=TRUE,breaks=5)
```

The code for the fitted Weibull function is:(Need the MASS package)

```
    fitdistr(data$grddia2,densfun=dweibull,start=list(scale=1,shape=2))
```

How do I plot both together on the same graph. I've attached the data set.

Also, bonus to anyone who can provide code that can achieve the same thing, but create a graph for each column of data. Many columns within a data set. Would be nice to have all graphs on the same page.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ra9c2kkk49vyyyc/Diameter%20Distribution.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code

```
library("ggplot2")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("MASS")

# Import dataset and filter the column "treeno"
# Use namespace dplyr:: explicitly because of conflict with MASS:: for function "select"
data <- read.csv("Diameter Distribution.csv") %>% 
  dplyr::select(-treeno)

# Function to provide the Weibull distribution for each column
# The distribution is calculated based on the estimated scale and shape parameters of the input
fitweibull <- function(column) {
  x <- seq(0,7,by=0.01)
  fitparam <- column %>%
    unlist %>% 
    fitdistr(densfun=dweibull,start=list(scale=1,shape=2))
  return(dweibull(x, scale=fitparam$estimate[1], shape=fitparam$estimate[2]))
}

# Apply function for each column then consolidate all in a data.frame
fitdata <-data %>%
  apply(2, as.list) %>% 
  lapply(FUN = fitweibull) %>% 
  data.frame()

# Display graphs
multiplyingFactor<-10
ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data=gather(data), aes(x=value, group=key, fill=key), alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line(data=gather(fitdata), aes(x=rep(seq(0,7,by=0.01),ncol(fitdata)), y=multiplyingFactor*value, group=key, color=key))
```

And the output figure
[image]

*Variant:* thanks to the wonderful ggplot2 package you can also have the graphs apart just by adding this final line of code

```
+ facet_wrap(~ key) + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Which gives you this other figure:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed. Also, thank you for explaining each section of code. It is extremely helpful and easy to reproduce.

Comment: Great. Can you please mark this question as answered

Comment: @faidherbard very nice plot but I wish your example had something a bit simpler to understand, I only have one weibull distribution so I am not sure how to adapt this.

Comment: @HermanToothrot just write `data <- read.csv("Diameter Distribution.csv") %>% dplyr::select(dbh10)` at line 8 and the rest works fine, just with the `dbh10` column. I gave the answer based on the data provided in the question from @derrick